# CUDA "convolution" as slow as OpenMP version

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to "convolve" a `featWidth * featHeight * 31` cube with another `modelWidth * modelHeight * 31` cube. The problem is that this kernel is quite slow (well, I manage to be quicker than a sequential CPU code, but as slow as a OpenMP version). I'm using a Quadro FX 1800 (yeah, 64 CUDA cores...).

```
__constant__ float d_model[31*22*22];
#define IMUL(a,b) ( __mul24((a), (b)) )
#define IMAD(a,b,c) ( __mul24((a), (b)) + (c) )
__global__ void dMatch(float *score, const int featWidth, const int featHeight, const int modelWidth, const int modelHeight, const int scoreWidth, const int scoreHeight)
{
  const int x = IMAD(blockIdx.x, blockDim.x, threadIdx.x);
  const int y = IMAD(blockIdx.y, blockDim.y, threadIdx.y);
  if(x < scoreWidth && y < scoreHeight)
  {
   const int scoreIdx = IMAD(x, scoreHeight, y);
   score[scoreIdx] = 0.f;
   const int baseFeatIdx = IMUL(x,scoreHeight) + IMAD(modelHeight-1, x, y);
   for(int z = 0; z < 31; ++z)
   {
     // Index positionning
     int featIdx =  IMAD(z, IMUL(featWidth,featHeight), baseFeatIdx);
     int modelIdx = IMUL(z, IMUL(modelWidth,modelHeight));

     float value = 0.f;

     // filter
     for(int xx=0; xx<modelWidth; xx++)
     {
       const int xxmodelIdx = IMAD(xx, modelHeight, modelIdx);
       const int xxfeatIdx = IMAD(xx, featHeight, featIdx);
       for(int yy=0; yy<modelHeight; yy++)
       {
         value += d_model[xxmodelIdx+yy] * tex1Dfetch(texFeatures,xxfeatIdx+yy);
       }
     }
     score[scoreIdx] += value;
  }
 }
}
```

Anyway, I launch this kernel with `8*8` threads in block and with a grid size of `(scoreWidth/8)*(scoreHeight/8)` (scoreWidth and scoreHeight are the resulting matrix sizes) . 
I'd like to know if you have any clue of what's wrong or what is rather slow in my code.

Edit:

A much faster version (150 ms drop for a 480 ms process!) thanks to tera:

```
__global__ void dMatch(float *score, const int featWidth, const int featHeight, const int modelWidth, const int modelHeight, const int scoreWidth, const int scoreHeight)
{
    const int y = IMUL(4,IMAD(blockIdx.x, blockDim.x, threadIdx.x));
    const int x = IMAD(blockIdx.y, blockDim.y, threadIdx.y);
    if(x < scoreWidth && y < scoreHeight)
    {
    const int scoreIdx = IMAD(x, scoreHeight, y);
    const int baseFeatIdx = IMUL(x,scoreHeight) + IMAD(modelHeight-1, x, y);
    float value=0.f, value1 = 0.f, value2 = 0.f, value3 = 0.f;
    float feat,feat1,feat2,feat3;

    // Index positionning
    int featIdx =  0;
    int modelIdx = 0;
    int xxmodelIdx;
    int xxfeatIdx; 
    float val;
    for(int z = 0; z < 31; ++z)
    {
        featIdx = IMAD(z,IMUL(featWidth,featHeight),baseFeatIdx);
        modelIdx = IMUL(z,IMUL(modelWidth,modelHeight));

        // filter
        for(int xx=0; xx<modelWidth; xx++)
        {
            xxmodelIdx  = IMAD(xx, modelHeight, modelIdx);
            xxfeatIdx = IMAD(xx, featHeight, featIdx);
            feat=tex1Dfetch(texFeatures,xxfeatIdx+0);
            feat1=tex1Dfetch(texFeatures,xxfeatIdx+1);
            feat2=tex1Dfetch(texFeatures,xxfeatIdx+2);
            feat3=tex1Dfetch(texFeatures,xxfeatIdx+3);
            for(int yy=0; yy<modelHeight; yy++)
            {
                val = d_model[xxmodelIdx+yy];
                value += val * feat;
                value1 += val * feat1;
                value2 += val * feat2;
                value3 += val * feat3;
                feat = feat1;
                feat1 = feat2;
                feat2 = feat3;
                feat3 = tex1Dfetch(texFeatures,xxfeatIdx+yy+4);
            }
        }
    }
    score[scoreIdx] = value;
    if(y+1 < scoreHeight)
        score[scoreIdx+1] = value1;
    if(y+2 < scoreHeight)
        score[scoreIdx+2] = value2;
    if(y+3 < scoreHeight)
        score[scoreIdx+3] = value3;
}
```

Launched with this `dim3 threads(16,16); dim3 grid(divup(scoreHeight,64), divup(scoreWidth,16));`.

Comment: Some quick thoughts: Use a texture bound to a 3D array to exploit 3D locality. Compute multiple results at nearby offsets in one pass to amortize the cost of fetching data. Get a decent GPU because your's is not that much faster than any halfway recent CPU anyway.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I'll try the 3D array, but I don't expect much from this. Of course my GPU isn't great... and I've got Intel Xeon W3520 @ 2.67GHz. Well... I'm waiting for my new video card (a GTX 680), I think I won't have any optimization problems with that one :)

Comment: I'd expect most from producing multiple outputs. Because the additional outputs essentially com for free.

Comment: @tera I don't get it. You want to compute the score value for different (x,y) positions?

Comment: Yes. Because the score value for an adjacent pixel only needs one surface of the cube to be fetched, all the other values from the volume of the cube have already been loaded for the score of the original pixel.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it and modified my code a little.

Answer (score 1):

What does the profiler says? The [NVidia NSight](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition)(plugin for Visual Studio on Windows and for [Eclipse](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-eclipse-edition) on Linux) allows you two see where the stalls are and provides various hints to optimize performance.

My guess (without looking on profiler) is that the blocks you have are too small. There are 32 threads inside warp which is basic scheduling element. NVIDIA GPU is able to be fast as it can hide the latency by operating on other threads while the current one is doing the previous instruction. While it is possible to have 8 blocks per SM (on Tesla and Fermi) or 16 (on Kepler) you still have 16-32 warps at peaks which can be quite small (I may be wrong but launching block have certain latency). I would consider using much larger blocks.

The texture fetch is sub-optimal if I understand the code correctly - the threads in warp differs by `modelHeight - 1` in `baseFeatId` and therefore in `featIdx` and `xxfeatIdx`. Therefore the texture fetch is entirely random and it does not exploit the data locality. Reversing `x` and `y` would make it more efficient.

However the good rule is to check with the profiler - if your problem is compute bound on GPU then you should concentrate on computing side. If your problem is memory bound the you should look on memory access patter. There might be several other parts which seems like spots to optimization but you won't know until you see what the bottleneck is. Once you know it you might want to read specific chapter on [best practices guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
Well I have updated my code, I launch larger blocks (`16x16`). I managed to achieve a 200 ms gain from my original non-optimized code. 

I know that I load twice the same data, and I'd like to avoid it.
For example, if the score `X` position is equal to `x+1` and model position is equal to `xx`, it loads the same data from texture as a `x` position and `xx+1` model position. I'm trying to avoid this and only load it once.

Since I reduced a lot the fetching rate to achieve my speedup, I think it's more like a memory bound.

Comment: @eg141840: I would go even higher (32*32?) if possible but this is diminishing returns. The repeated loads are not the problem as you are going through cache (constant or texture) - they might be just wasteful. You might want to use Kepler's `__shfl` function to load from 32 consecutive locations and broadcast it to various threads. In general GPUs are way ahead of CPUs and FPGAs in terms of memory access rate so once you get the memory access right you should be able to achieve large speedup.

Comment: Well @Maciej Piechotka, I can't use kepler's function as I have at present a Quadro FX 1800. But yeah, the compute load is huge too, I'd like to use even larger blocks but I can't, it uses too many registers for my GPU.

Comment: @eg141840: I haven't had much experience with Tesla (generation) but if there is too many registers they should spill to local memory - not prevent from running larger blocks (and - I guess - they should be streamed instead of occupying registers but I don't remember that) - especially that register allocation is done during compile time while grid size is set during runtime. As of load - the important part is what is stalling as one load is interleaved with another.